# Strange difference between Integer variable and Array variable

Tags: ruby

```
a = 1
def bla x
 x = x + 1
end

bla a # =>2 when I use bla to add 1, it return 2

a # => 1 but it get back to the original value

a = [1]
```

but Array

```
def bla x
 x << 1
end

bla a # => [1,1]

a # =>[1,1] stay in the new value
```

Could Anybody tell me why it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between **mutable** and **immutable**  objects.

- `Numerical` is immutable; in other words, if you had the object `1`, you cannot change its value to `2`. `1` and `2` will always be different objects, having different object ids. What `1+1` is doing is returning back a newly created `2`, that is a different object from `1`.
- `Array`, `Hash`, `String` are mutable; in other words, if you had the object `[]`, you can change it to `[1]` retaining its identity, and that is what your code does. Even though the value is now different, it is the same object as `[]` before.

But in your case, you are comparing `Fixnum#+` and `Array#<<` and claiming they are different. That is not strange. They are different methods, why do you expect them to be the same? In fact, as mu points out, if you do `a+[1]`, that does not change `a`. It does what is comparable to `Fixnum#+`: create a new object and return it.

What your question should be really asking is: why is there no counterpart `Numerical#<<` that behaves like `Array#<<`? The mutable vs. immutable difference above is the answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because calling the `<<` method will edit the value at the reference to the array.

If you didn't want this to happen, you could do:

```
def bla x
  x + [1]
end
```

This works by concatenating the array, `x` with the array [1], returning a new array from this operation.

or:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > bla a.dup
 => [1, 1] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 > a
 => [1]
```

This will use [Object#dup](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001015), which will do a shallow copy.

If you wanted a deep copy, you can use [Object#clone](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001014).

Comment: Although I'm not a ruby expert, I doubt this is accurate. In about every other language, *everything* is a reference and those references are passed by value. The only difference is that some object can be modified in-place.

Answer (score 2):

This version of your integer `bla`:

```
def bla x
  x += 1
end
a = 1
bla a
```

is closer to your array one. But, even this one won't change `a` because `Fixnum` instances are immutable; if `Fixnum` instances weren't immutable you'd have people changing the value of 1 and that would just create a big mess.

This version of your array `bla`:

```
def bla x
  x + [1]
end
a = [1]
bla a
```

is closer to your integer one. This array-bla will leave `a` unmodified.

Your array-bla changes `a` because `x << 1` is the same as `x.push(1)` and the `push` method modifies the array. The `x` that your array-bla see is a reference that points to the same object that `a` does.

Answer (score 1):

'<<' operator always append value to existing variable(by reference) but others does not.